# Disable horizontal scrolling on an overlay but maintain scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have an overlay menu that consists of a lot of vertical columns which overflow the window width. We navigate through this menu by horizontally scrolling.

Clicking on one of these columns will bring up a "detailed" view, and centers the column to the window. In this view I want to lock the horizontal scrolling so the user can only just scroll down through the detailed view.

However, the issue is that I want to maintain the `scrollLeft` position when I lock the scroll so the column remains centered on the page.

I've tried a couple methods already:

1. Setting `max-width: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden` on `body`, `html`, etc.
2. Setting the parent container to `overflow-x: hidden;` successfully locks the scroll but it resets the scroll position. And if I try a `translate` or `left` setting to readjust, the parts are cropped.

Comment: It sounds like you want the function that scrolls your slider to be temporarily disabled after an user clicks it to look at the details. Maybe create a (boolean) variable  that prevents the functions that lets you scroll horizontally from running?